# Unity3D C# private variable will not update with public setter function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Minimal code from BoardScript.cs

```
public class BoardScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private float angle;
    private static BoardScript instance;

    void Awake() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
     }

    Start(){
        angle = 0.5f;
    }

    Update(){
        Debug.Log("angle = " + angle); // logged angle never changes.
        Debug.Log("GetAngle() returns " + GetAngle()); // also never changes...
     }

    public SetAngle(float arg) {
        angle = arg;
        Debug.Log("angle set to " + angle);
        // Above always logs new angle as called fron Settings.cs. 
    }

    private float GetAngle() { // only use is for debugging this issue.
        Debug.Log("angle is " + angle); // Does not log newly set angle.
        return angle;
    }
}
```

Minimal code Settings.cs

```
private GameObject theBoard;

public void SetBoardAngule(float arg) {
    theBoard.GetComponent<BoardScript>().SetAngle(arg);
    Debug.Log("Settings - SetAngle to " + arg); // Logs correct angle.
}
```

The update function logs "angle = 0.5" no matter what it gets set to in method SetAngle().  This seems terribly simple to me.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure, that you are calling `GetAngle` on the same instance, that you are calling `SetAngle` on? You should share the code, where you call `SetAngle`, too

Comment: I think so - see expanded code sample.

Comment: Instead of `theBoard.GetComponent<BoardScript>().SetAngle(arg);` try `BoardScript.instance.SetAngle(arg)`

Comment: Won't compile like that.

Comment: @RigidBody won't compile because your `instance` is private. The singleton should be public for access though.

Comment: And always call `BoardScript.instance.function`

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, that got me going again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first: your getter setter is all good.

other stuff:
first thing if you are coming from Java world, you do not need to create functions for getter setters:

```
public SetAngle(float arg) {
        angle = arg;
        Debug.Log("angle set to " + angle);
        // Above always logs new angle as called fron Settings.cs. 
    }

    private float GetAngle() { // only use is for debugging this issue.
        Debug.Log("angle is " + angle); // Does not log newly set angle.
        return angle;
    }
```

can be converted to:

```
public float Angle
{
    get{return _angle;}
    set{_angle = value;}
}
```

second, i'm not sure why you do destroy the object, without creating one on awake: but here what you do is, if object doesn't exist, create one, .... otherwise if object exist, destroy current, but not creating another one.

third: which also relate to second: we are creating singleton, to have only one instance of our class, if that's what you want, there are tons of way to do it, but you have to set your variable accordingly: 
currently you are setting the value on (this instance) which may change from the (stored instance), and once that happen, you loss pointers, and you have to call it on the singleton class:

```
public float Angle
{
    get{return BoardScript.instance._angle;}
    set{BoardScript.instance._angle = value;}
}
```

instead of:

```
public float Angle
{
    get{return this._angle;}
    set{this._angle = value;}
}
```

forth: which again is related to second:
at first your object instance will be stored inside instance variable, but if you creating another object which call awake (i'm forgotten how awake worked and got invoked) that object will cause current object to get disposed, i'm not sure if this is the behaviour that you want, just saying...

```
void Awake() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @RigidBody it's nice that i could be useful after so long

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by commentators, change

```
private static BoardScript instance;
```

to

```
public BoardScript instance;
```